# PHP's GD not showing image correctly

Tags: php, image, gd

I have created a script to create an image using GD and PHP. But when I run the code, it shows something like

> ����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default
>   quality ��C    $.'
>   ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C 
>   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��i"��
>   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
>   ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
>   $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��(��**���BT;$�o�s֠��K�/�q�3ʣ�8Ǯ~��R�j
>   ���KE$쨥��G$������i$u=
>   R����i�8lsZ���[vF�Rը��>�\Ĳ$�"�T��͡;�M;2��QE-U�ZH���4(���ͬ�***)iG����䌖�\zs�L
>   "���8e�Џ�@�$�QE ���hZ(��4��1bU�m����ZǞ�m��\��8
>   ���r3۵s��.e�h$!�pAl���#����9�I��JS],uqU���Uj*��%��.......

instead of correct things and browser also shows

> The image “`http://localhost/ttoe/ttoe.php?move=p`” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Please help me!!

Comment: Try to add `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` before image output.

Comment: @CORRUPT You are too fast in giving answer in comments. :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar if it is not a big deal, there is no honor to get reputation for it (IMHO). You still may post it as answer though, because I'm not providing any explaination with it.

Comment: @CORRUPT After adding `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`, browser shows: `The image “http://localhost/ttoe/ttoe.php?move=p” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Comment: There might be errors, while you executing GD script to create it. Check response output with searching something like `error` via the seach bar.

Comment: You almost certainly have a BOM in your files. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors/17010390#17010390