# PHP's base64_decode returns wrong result working in IIS

Tags: php, wcf, iis, base64, jpeg

I'm trying to show a jpg that was previously encoded in a WCF web service using:

```
<?php
require_once '../inc/config.php';
[...]
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo base64_decode($doc['BDATA']);
```

But I'm getting a

```
Can't display the image because it contains errors.
```

I've decoded the base64 string in this web app [www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) and the result is right, but different that the one I'm getting with `base64_decode`, which is wrong.

**Edit**: I have two enviroments using the same code: Test and Production. It works fine in Test, but not in Production, so I'm thinking in some configuration problem.

I'm working with `PHP 5.5.9` in `Microsoft IIS`.

An example of a string that base64_decode isn't decoding well:
`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`

Any ideas?

**Edit 2**: If I comment this line 
`require_once '../inc/config.php';` 
and copy the code from config.php to my actual file, it works fine. What could be happening?

Comment: is that image is empty ? white image !

Comment: Yes, it's just an example. It fails with all images.

Comment: can you put example of real image for further test ?

Comment: A white image is a real image. My code should show a white image, but it's showing an error: 'Can't display the image because it contains errors.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [base_64_decode manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) comments

> php <= 5.0.5's base64_decode( $string ) will assume that a space is
> meant to be a + sign where php >= 5.1.0's base64_decode( $string )
> will no longer make that assumption

To fix this behavior try this code

```
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
$decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
```

As this is no't your case then you have to [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors)
Because every thing work fine for me here on (WAMP)

EDIT:
As in our below conversation

> There are a lot of things that may corrupt header for example , if
> your file encoding is UTF-8 then you should save it as UTF-8 Without
> bom you can do this using notepad ++ , also make sure if you use FTP
> that your client didn't any chars to your file , rather than that
> every thing should work fine

Comment: Still the same error: 'Can't display the image because it contains errors.'

Comment: The thing is, if I remove the header function, the browser shows the stream. That stream is different that the one I get in the web app.

Comment: I've edited my initial question, please take a look at it. By the way, I'm using IIS, not Apache, and I think that maybe could be some problem with the charset configuration or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of things that may corrupt header for example , if your file encoding is UTF-8 then you should save it as `UTF-8 Without bom` you can do this using notepad ++ , also make sure if you use FTP that your client didn't any chars to your file , rather than that every thing should work fine .

Comment: I did what you said, but still the same error. Again, I dont think it's  a problem with the header, because if I don't print any header I still get a wrong stream.

Comment: i will attach file to you please test it on your server and give me result back , Ok

Comment: I'm not using a FTP. I'm coding directly on the server since I have access to the server machine by TeamViewer.

Comment: Please upload this file as it's to your machine and test
http://ge.tt/3FtGRuf1/v/0

Comment: That code works. I don't know where is my problem then.

Comment: it's HEADER problem :D believe me 
just fix your file or use my file as base to your code, also you can accept this answer i will modify it

Comment: I commented your "header()..." line and I got a valid stream. I did the same in my file and I got an invalid (and different) stream. I'm not using headers.

Comment: Take a look at "Edit 2" in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Solved! I was including a "config.php". I changed the char codification of that file to UTF-8 Without bom and it worked! Thank you very much for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

base64 encoding is not completely standardised.

Some implementations use different characters, so you'll have to replace those characters before you run your decode.

[further details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: I should say that I have two enviroments: Test and Production and it's working fine in Test. I'll edit my question.