# images are not displayed or they are shown only locally

Tags: php, html, image

I would like to display some images which their URL is saved in DB, but the images are not diplayed and when I right click on the image and select "view image" I see this message:

`http://localhost/imdbImage.php?url=http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg cannot be diplayed because it contains errors`

This is my code:

```
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
?> 
    <tr>
       <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
       <td> ....
       ...
    </tr>
```

Also, I see this warning in php error log:

`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(Null): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/imdbImage.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/movielist.php`

while imdbImage.php is:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
//URL for IMDb Image.
$url = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['url']);
echo file_get_contents($url);   //THIS IS LINE 6 //
?>
```

When I try with the following code, it only shows the images locally. 
   `<td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>`

Could someone kindly let me know what is the problem with my code and why the images are not shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OMG! The problem was solved only by removing one blank line!!!

I wrote `<?php` in imdbImage.php file in the second line.. so the first line was empty. 
I found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors) (Thanks to Johan)

`You must not output anything before header(). Just start your document with <?php followed by the code for displaying the image. Skip the html tags. Do not even write a single blankline before header().`

Hope it would be useful for someone else too :)