# PHP cannot load image and display it

Tags: php, image, header, content-type, loadimage

I am trying to make a php script to load image and display it depending on $_GET paramters.

I want to use this later to load image into my mobile application(Android).

The problem is I cannot make image to display. I use the code below:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
readfile($path);
```

But when I open page in firefox I get error:

```
Image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

What is more I tried different approach and I can get image display in html code(I dont want this - it requires to remove headers in java android - but it proves that path is correct)

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($path) ).'"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any output before?

Comment: Ensure that you do not output any characters before the header is sent! Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors

Comment: I only see error, which means that header is included correcly and my browser tries to open page as image.

Comment: @Alek you must check the output

Comment: Ok, I got a space at the begining. That might be a problem

Comment: There was a space in a file where I connected to mysql database to verify paramters. Removed it and it works.