# laravel image processing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The following code working fine when use in simple php but when i use the same in laravel view then it show me the error

Code

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Error in laravel

[image]

Simple PHP output

[image]

Comment: try setting the correct content-type in your header: `header('Content-type:image/png');`

Comment: yes i did it before but the result is the same

Comment: Where is the code you have shown us located? Inside a view? `header()` must be called before any other PHP output. Also check your logfile (laravel.log) for further clues on the issue.

Comment: The "error" you're seeing is the actual PNG data you're trying to send. If you check [the PNG spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) you'll see that the first eight bytes of any PNG file are 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10; the three ASCII-printable characters of that (80, 78, 71) are "PNG". This is followed by an "IHDR" chunk. That does rather point to the problem being a Content-Type one. Confirm the problem by using a web debugger (like your browser's debugging tools) to look at the headers sent in the response and see if the Content-Type header is there.

Comment: (Is this your *entire* view code? Can we see it all, for real, from the `<?php` onwards?) By the looks of [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#other-response-types) (see the example under "Creating Custom Responses") it looks to me like you may just need to add the header in your controller after rendering the view.

Comment: As I pointed out earlier, the problem is that you are executing `header();` *inside* your view. You need to outsource that code to your controller. Having code inside your views is not a good practice. You need to use something like this inside your controller: `return response()->view('hello', $data, 200)->header('Content-Type', $type);`

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704951/8317643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. All you need is to add an "exit" at the end.

Code:

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
exit;
```

EDIT:

The main problem is that you are trying to change the response header into the view. You need to change it on the controller function that call the view. For example:

```
return \Response::view('myView')->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```

And then, in your PHP code all you need to do is remove the first line:

```
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I tried OP's code and it works fine without `exit();`

Comment: with exit the code start working but i dont want to exit

Comment: @Sam Why don't you want to exit?

Comment: @Matt Gibson using `exit();` in laravel inside a view isn't exactly what you would call neat and clean...