# PHP session start "Cannot send session cookie and cache limiter"

Tags: php

I've changed my hosting server from a Windows to a Linux system. But when I run my PHP program, I get this errors:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p/y/c/francis/html/login/login.php:2) in /home/content/p/y/c/francis/html/login/login.php on line 4
```

and

```
 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/p/y/c/francis/html/login/login.php:2) in /home/content/p/y/c/francis/html/login/login.php on line 4
```

This is the code of my program:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username  = $_POST['username'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect(***,***,***);
mysql_select_db("phploginregister") or die("Couldn't find db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows != 0)
{

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    //check to see if they match!
    if ($username == $dbusername && md5($password) == $dbpassword)
    {
    echo "You're in! <a href='member.php'>Click</a> here to enter the member page.";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;    
    }

    else
        echo "Incorrect password";
}
else
    die("That user doens't exist!");

}
else
    die("Please enter an username and password");



?>
```

What is wrong in the code, because it workend fine on a Windows host...

Comment: Are you including this file anywhere? You need to make sure there is no output sent before `session_start`. Your Windows server probably had output buffering configured, that's why it didn't give an error.

Comment: You're probably dealing with a BOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558172/utf-8-bom-signature-in-php-files

Comment: SOLVED ! The problem was a space/newline before the script

Comment: @Quasdunk with a BOM output is started on line 0

Comment: @user947093 post this as an answer

Comment: @Darhazer Yep, you're right - my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a leading BOM, new line or other whitespace character before the opening `<?php` tag.

The errors talk about `line 2` and `line 4`, but in the actual code above `session_start()` is called on `line 3`. Therefore, leading whitespace is the problem...

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because there are some output before you have initiated session_start(); This could be caused because of your editor that include a BOM character in the beginning of your file. Try open the code in notepad and see if there are any lines before session_start(), (spaces) or things like that and remove them.

To fix your editor if it add a bom in your file, you need to go to your settings and turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should add

`ob_start();`

in the **first** of your code

and in the **bottom** add

`ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();`

because of

session send headers to server , also you added echo ( this also tell server its html with headers )

server now has to headers  so use the  `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` to work :)

Comment: ob_end_flush() is enough, no need to call ob_get_contents(), which returns the ob content