# "headers already sent" error after file upload

Tags: php

After I uploaded my files this kind of error is occurred. But there is no any errors in my localhost. What kind of error is this? How to fix this?

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/lahiruca/public_html/events/includes/links.php:1) in
>   /home/lahiruca/public_html/events/includes/header.php on line 1

(from the comments)

```
<?php session_start();?> 
<div class="header"> 
<div class="logo"></div> 
<div class="right_header"> 
<div class="top_right_header"> 
  <ul> <?php if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){ ?>
```

Comment: you have spaces before `<?php`?

Comment: @parallax: from which file is that code? from `links.php` or from `header.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says: You are trying to send headers (using the function `session_start`), but headers are allready sent.

Ways headers can be sent:

- output is generated: this can be intended, like you allready did an echo,
- or unintended (most of the times there can be some sort of whitespace in front of you `<?php` code. Or after a closing `?>` in an included file
- the `header` function

Comment: <?php session_start();?>
    <div class="header">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="right_header">
        <div class="top_right_header">
              <ul>
          <?php
     
         if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
          ?>

Comment: this is my code. is there any prob?

Comment: Depending on the PHP-version and settings it could also be a [BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558172/utf-8-bom-signature-in-php-files) before the `<?php`, which is probably not shown in the editor. You have to find out how to remove the BOM with your editor (or use an other editor).

Comment: my guess is there is something before that line, The stuff that prints `<html>` for instance. Sending `<html><head></head><body>` to the browser is really what we are talking about: this is ouptut. You should not do any output before you call that session function. (please take care to add stuff like this to your question, you'll get better help. Don't add it as a comment)

Comment: my problem is fixed. I have included link.php in index.php before include header.php. And there was a div tag before header include. So I remove session_start() from header.php and put in to the top of index.php. It works. thanks for helping me.