# issue with returned JSON MIME type

Tags: php, ios, json, mamp, afnetworking

I have a php API which return a `JSON` data, when trying to receive that `JSON` from my application, I got the follwoing error:

```
"Expected content type {(\n    \"text/json\",\n    \"application/json\",\n    \"text/javascript\"\n)}, got text/html";
```

You may reply that php API isn't returning valid JSON, well, I checked that on Json Lint and it's a valid JSON, also, the header is set to `JSON`

```
    header( 'Content-Type: text/json' );
    echo '{"Response":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

I also checked the MAMP `mime.types` file  and it include the JSON mime type correctly.

The only thing I am suspecting on is when I call the API via the browser, I get the JSON as expected, but when shwing the source code of the page, it shows up with 2 empty lines at the beginning. Like below.

```
1-   
2-
3-    {"Response":[{"Product ID":"12037","Product Title":"RIng 14K Cloud 9","Product Description":"RIng 14K Cloud 9","Product Wholsale Price":"$255","Product Sale Price":"$460","Category Id":"55","Category Name":"Rings","Product Image":"http:\/\/192.163.1.87:8888\/xxxxxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/12\/150101.jpg","Product Sub Images":["http:\/\/192.163.1.87:8888\/xxxxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/12\/150101.jpg"],"SKU":"150101-50","Quantity":"1","Size":"50","Color":"Y","Manufacturer":"xxxxxx"},{"Product ID":"12039","Product Title":"Ring 14K Cloud 9","Product Description":"Ring 14K Cloud 9","Product Wholsale Price":"$255","Product Sale Price":"$460","Category Id":"55","Category Name":"Rings","Product Image":"http:\/\/192.163.1.87:8888\/xxxxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/12\/150101.jpg","Product Sub Images":["http:\/\/192.163.1.87:8888\/xxxxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/12\/150101.jpg"],"SKU":"150101-52","Quantity":"1","Size":"52","Color":"Y","Manufacturer":"xxxxxx"}]}
```

Does this have to do with any thing in the php code or MAMP server? Thanx in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to consume the json data when you get the error?

Comment: Change the content type to "application/json"

Comment: The correct header for json is `header('Content-type: application/json')`. Try that.

Comment: Look for places that would output white spaces before you set the header and remove them.

Comment: Check if your PHP files use the right line-endings and if no (hidden) characters are before your `<?php` opening tags

Comment: @thaJeztah Hi, can you explain what is line-endings ?

Comment: Most editors allow you to save your file in 'UNIX' or 'Windows' format. Both systems use different characters to mark the end of a line. In WebDevelopment the consensus is to use UNIX (LF) line endings and UTF-8 encoding. Also make sure that (if your editor has this option) you *disable* 'BOM header' when saving; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558172/utf-8-bom-signature-in-php-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output has two empty lines at the beginning.  Once something is output, you can no longer use the `header()` function to change any of the headers.

You may have some issues with spaces before or after the php open/close tags on some of your files.  Make sure that the `<?php` tag on every file is the very first thing in the file; check the file encoding; don't leave trailing whitespace after php close tags, or even remove all your closing `?>` tags from the end of files.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Actually I did exactly all you mention, removed all closing tags, there is no `echo` on the file before the header. Is there any php function to force JSON header or something else?

Comment: Are you including any other files?

Comment: I am including another file, which is what is causing the issue. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Also, I believe the correct header type for JSON is application/json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

If using JSONP, it should be application/javascript:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```