# Missing value in associative array, but value visible with var_dump()

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a simple associative array called `$product`.

This is how it looks with `var_dump[$product]`

```
array(5) {
  ["sku"]=>
  string(9) "001R00610"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "Xerox 001R00610 Transfer Kit"
  ["image_label"]=>
  string(28) "Xerox 001R00610 Transfer Kit"
  ["small_image_label"]=>
  string(28) "Xerox 001R00610 Transfer Kit"
  ["thumbnail_label"]=>
  string(28) "Xerox 001R00610 Transfer Kit"
}
```

But when i try and get the value of sku with `var_dump($product['sku'])` it returns null?

`var_dump($product['sku']);`

returns

`NULL`

I have noticed there seems to be a linebreak in at `sku`, but i am not sure what is causing this or if this is related to my issue.

Comment: Show what you get for `var_dump(array_keys($product));`

Comment: This doesn't seem possible, however if there is a linebreak in the `"sku"` key, then then it would be something like `"sku\n"` and not `"sku"`? Did you edit the result of `var_dump()` to get rid of the linebreak?

Comment: If this is from a loaded CSV file - check for a [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558172/utf-8-bom-signature-in-php-files) at the start of the file - so `sku` has a few control characters at the start.  A quick check is for the length of the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

As suggested by @aynber i tried doing a `var_dump(array_keys($product));` which returned this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "sku"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "image_label"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "small_image_label"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "thumbnail_label"
}
```

Lenght of array key sku is wrong.

Array is created from CVS as pointed out by @Nigel Ren. After converting from `UTF-8-BOM` to `UTF-8` it return the expected value.

`var_dump($product['sku']);` returns `string(9) "001R00610"`

Answer (score 1):

php doesnt print line breaks in keys with var_dump, they become space characters, but are still in the accessor a linebreak. This code:

```
$obj = array("foo\r" => "bar");
var_dump($obj);
```

prints this:

```
array(1) { ["foo "]=> string(3) "bar" }
```

and cannot be accessed by this:

```
$obj["foo"]; //returns null
$obj["foo "]; //returns null
```

only:

```
$obj["foo\n"] //returns bar
```

works as array keys get compared as bits(I think).

Comment: Excellent point Shura. I didn't know it turned into a space, does it? Testing. Well, it doesn't really. It is still a linebreak (see html source) but that looks like a space in your browser. Regretably, **puntable** doesn't seem to be reacting very much, so we will probably never know if this was the problem.